# Core Data--pass name of entity or reference to entire entity?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm making a simple bank account tracker, for self-instructional purposes. I'm using Core Data to store three entities, related as in the screenshot:

[image]

WMMGTransaction objects are simply stored as they are recorded, and extracted as needed to feed tableviews and detail views. This will be done via `NSFetchedResultsController` and a predicate. I'm using MagicalRecord to access Core Data, if that matters.

My question is this:

When I pass `WMMGAccount` data from one VC to another, such as when creating a new account, or when selecting one from a list (via delegation as a rule), does it matter if I pass a reference to the entire entity, or can I just use an `NSString` bearing the `.name` of the account and identify the account when required with a predicate and an `NSFetchedResultsController`? I guess this is a strategy question, and may generate discussion, rather than having a cut and dried answer, but I'm wrestling with it, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: What's an FRC? Google appears not to know either.

Comment: Sorry, shorthand for NSFetchedResultsController...see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking if you should pass an object to the code that needs it, or if you should pass information that could be used to look up the same object again.

Unless you need to use the managed object on a different thread or queue, you should always pass the actual object. No sense re-fetching an object you already have. It's extra work and code complexity that (unless there are some unusual extenuating details you didn't mention) won't help in any way.

If you **are** needing to use the object on a different queue or thread, passing information that can be used to look it up is the correct approach. But in that case-- don't pass the value of one of the properties. Use the managed object ID.
Core Data won't force `name` values to be unique, while the object's `managedObjectID` **is** unique. It's also faster when retrieving the object, because you can use `objectForID:` or `existingObjectForID:` instead of performing a fetch.